What is meaning of Backpropagation
Is there anyone who can explain Backpropagation and Feedforward propagation in terms that a Physics student would understand?

A deep neural networks is mathematically a composition of many functions (called "layers"). Given an input vector $x$, we calculate
\begin{align*} 
x^{(1)} &= f_0(x; W^{(0)}) \\
x^{(2)} &= f_1(x^{(1)}; W^{(1)}) \\
&\cdots \\
x^{(k)} &= f_{k-1}(x^{(k-1)}; W^{(k-1)}) \\
\hat y &= f_k(x^{(k)}; W^{(k)}) \\
l &= L(y, \hat y)
\end{align*}
The last line is a scalar loss function that represents how bad the output vector $\hat y$ of the neural network is compared to what is in the dataset ($y$).
A "forward pass" is just calculating the prediction $\hat y$ and loss $l$ from $x$ by going through all the layers $f_0$ to $f_k$ as indicated by the equations above. "Backpropagation" is calculating the gradient of $l$ with respect to the weights $W^{(i)}$. Applying the chain rule allows us to calculate the gradients with respect to $W^{(k)}$, then $W^{(k-1)}$, ..., $W^{(0)}$, as indicated in the right column below. (The left column computes gradients with respect to intermediate "activations" $x^{(i)}$. The order in which the computations are done is row by row in the equations below, going left to right in each row.)
\begin{align*}
&  & \frac{\partial l}{\partial W^{(k)}_{\alpha\beta}} &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat y_\gamma} \frac{\partial \hat y_\gamma}{\partial W^{(k)}_{\alpha\beta}} \\ 
\frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(k)}_\alpha} &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat y_\gamma} \frac{\partial \hat y_\gamma}{\partial x^{(k)}_\alpha} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial W^{(k-1)}_{\alpha\beta}} &=  \frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(k)}_\gamma}\frac{\partial x^{(k)}_\gamma}{\partial W^{(k-1)}_{\alpha\beta}} \\ 
\frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(k-1)}_\alpha} &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(k)}_\gamma} \frac{\partial x^{(k)}_\gamma}{\partial x^{(k-1)}_\alpha} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial W^{(k-2)}_{\alpha\beta}} &=  \frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(k-1)}_\gamma}\frac{\partial x^{(k-1)}_\gamma}{\partial W^{(k-2)}_{\alpha\beta}} \\ 
&\cdots & &\cdots \\
\frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(1)}_\alpha} &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(2)}_\gamma} \frac{\partial x^{(2)}_\gamma}{\partial x^{(1)}_\alpha} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial W^{(0)}_{\alpha\beta}} &=  \frac{\partial l}{\partial x^{(1)}_\gamma}\frac{\partial x^{(1)}_\gamma}{\partial W^{(0)}_{\alpha\beta}} \\ 
\end{align*}
Since we're going from the last layer to the first layer, it's like going "backwards", hence the name "back propagation".
(Since you said you're a physics student, I'm using Einstein's summation notation, where repeated indices ($\gamma$ in all equations above) are implicitly summed over.)
